# How to draw stick diagram of a function

Tags: circuit-design, cmos, diagram, vlsi

I am a student of computer science and engineering. We have VLSI design in current semester. Now i am having trouble drawing stick diagram for a given equation. What is the step by step procedure for drawing a stick diagram?

Suppose given `Y=~((A+B+C).D)` What is the step by step procedure to draw the stick diagram? Kindly explain as easily as possible.

Edit: I understand the basics of drawing stick diagrams. But below is an example in the book. How the output is connected to source of D in NMOS i don't understand. As well why ground is connected to drain of A and drain of B.
[image]

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials to be found when you search for "how to draw stick diagram". There are even Youtube videos. Why do you require an explanation especially for you when there are plenty to be found? Also, it will have been explained in your class.

Comment: Updated the question with actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go here: https://www.slideshare.net/hhkamat/vlsi-stic-daigram-jce
and look at sheet 5:

[image]

and sheet 15:

[image]

Note how there's no sign of any logic expressions like

Y=~((A+BC)D)

The stick diagram is not used for this.

You will first have to translate Y=~((A+BC)D) into a **circuit with logic gates**. Then fill in the logic gates with **transistor schematics**.

Then in order to understand the **layout** better and see how it relates to the **schematic** a stick diagram can be used.

I suggest that from the layout picture you included, use the stick diagram method to draw the **transistor schematic**. Then from that derive the formula describing the logical behavior (Y=~((A+BC)D) ).

Comment: Yes i know stick diagram is used for transistor schematic. As i am having trouble in understanding the given stick diagram in my question i think i am missing something.